# Disabling safe mode or removing apps from safe mode

Tags: motorola-droid-3, safe-mode

I use a Droid 3 which has not yet been rooted. I need to remove access to the Browser or the Play Store. I already have an app called "program encrypting" which disables access to selected apps unless the user has a password. However, when the user enters safe mode, all downloaded apps are disabled, allowing the user to use the Browser and the Play Store.

I am curious if it is possible to disable safe mode in some way, or changing the button combination to enable it. I would also be fine with removing those applications from appearing in safe mode. I am new to rooting and such, and I would appreciate being able to remove access to these apps in the safest, quickest way possible.

Answer (score 1):

That's something I'd say is impossible without rooting. Safe mode is for the case an app goes havoc, so it must disable all user apps (for the havoc-app to not be started, so one can uninstall it or clear its cache/data). Which means, in order to exclude an app from being excluded (oops), this app must be "converted" to be a system app (i.e. it must be installed on the `/system` partition) -- which only is possible with root-permissions (or if the app ships within the ROM).

Answer (score 1):

It happens to be that there is a way to block safe mode without rooting, however I am not sure if there's any free way. There's a filter software called MMGuardian, which blocks safe mode by setting the device's password to a master password (which the user doesn't know) and when the device boots up, the password sets itself to the users password. However, since MMGaurdian isn't activated in Safe Mode, in safe mode the password remains the master password, restricting access. Here's a link to their website: https://www.mmguardian.com/ Hope I helped!